# How do you customize your mac app store page

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

I've seen customized mac app store pages with their own backgrounds but haven't found where to do this.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this forum post Apple has to hand pick you to do this.
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=674387